# How to do a "multi-indexed" groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to start off by saying I'm a beginner in python, but I have this DataFrame here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'countingVariable': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'color': ['red', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange'], 'foods': ['apple', 'pepper', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'pepper', 'pepper', 'apple', 'apple']})
b = df.groupby(['color', 'foods']).count().sort_values(['countingVariable', 'foods', 'color'], ascending = [False, False, False])
```

where b looks like this:

```
               countingVariable
color  foods                   
yellow apple                  3
red    pepper                 2
orange apple                  2
       pepper                 1
red    apple                  1
```

but I want it to look like this output:

```
               countingVariable
color  foods                   
yellow apple                  3
red    pepper                 2
       apple                  1
orange apple                  2
       pepper                 1
```

so the program will find the highest count then put that at the top along with the rest of the group it belongs to

Comment: You misspecified one of the colors in your `DataFrame`. I updated it to reproduce your input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to `.reindex` on the 0th level to obtain your sorting (food by highest count then descending within food). This works because `pd.unique` preservers order.

```
import pandas as pd

b = b.reindex(b.index.unique(level=0), level=0)
```

#### Output:

```
               countingVariable
color  foods                   
yellow apple                  3
red    pepper                 2
       apple                  1
orange apple                  2
       pepper                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. You show your initial output as

```
print(b)
               countingVariable
color  foods                   
yellow apple                  3
red    pepper                 2
orange apple                  2
       pepper                 1
red    apple                  1
```

Yet, when I use your exact code I get a different output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'countingVariable': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
  'color': ['red', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'orange', 'orange', 'yellow', 'orange'],
  'foods': ['apple', 'pepper', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'pepper', 'pepper', 'apple', 'apple']
    })
b = df.groupby(['color', 'foods']).count().sort_values(['countingVariable', 'foods', 'color'],
               ascending = [False, False, False])

print(b)
               countingVariable
color  foods                   
yellow apple                  3
orange pepper                 2
       apple                  2
red    pepper                 1
       apple                  1
```

This seems like the output you actually want.

**EDIT**

Perhaps the data you've posted is somehow different from what you are actually using?

Comment: Hm. That is strange. It looks like what you copied somehow changed the third to last color from orange to red though

Comment: Actually, @ALollz corrected your post - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751373/how-to-do-a-multi-indexed-groupby/54752014?noredirect=1#comment96286683_54751373). With his edit, I get the same output you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
df.groupby(['color', 'foods']).count().sort_values('countingVariable', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
               countingVariable
color  foods                   
yellow apple                  3
orange apple                  2
       pepper                 2
red    apple                  1
       pepper                 1
```